# How to remove xmlns=“” from xml request

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, cxf

i am using **CXF 3.0.8** to invoke a web service:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", name = "INotificationGateway")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class, com.microsoft.schemas._2003._10.serialization.ObjectFactory.class, org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.notificationsgateway.ObjectFactory.class, com.microsoft.schemas._2003._10.serialization.arrays.ObjectFactory.class})
public interface INotificationGateway {

    @WebResult(name = "SendSMSResult", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
    @Action(input = "http://tempuri.org/INotificationGateway/SendSMS", output = "http://tempuri.org/INotificationGateway/SendSMSResponse", fault = {@FaultAction(className = INotificationGatewaySendSMSEAICustomErrorFaultFaultMessage.class, value = "http://tempuri.org/INotificationGateway/SendSMSEAICustomErrorFault")})
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "SendSMS", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", className = "org.tempuri.SendSMS")
    @WebMethod(operationName = "SendSMS", action = "http://tempuri.org/INotificationGateway/SendSMS")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "SendSMSResponse", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", className = "org.tempuri.SendSMSResponse")
    public org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.notificationsgateway.NotificationResponse sendSMS(
        @WebParam(name = "SendSMSNotificationRequest")
        org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.notificationsgateway.SendSMSNotificationRequest sendSMSNotificationRequest
    ) throws INotificationGatewaySendSMSEAICustomErrorFaultFaultMessage;

}
```

and the object i send in the service request is:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "SendSMSNotificationRequest", propOrder = { "isArabic", "mobileNo", "refrenceId", "templateCode",
        "templateValues" })
public class SendSMSNotificationRequest {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "IsArabic", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NotificationsGateway", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<Boolean> isArabic;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "MobileNo", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NotificationsGateway", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> mobileNo;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "RefrenceId", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NotificationsGateway", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> refrenceId;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "TemplateCode", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NotificationsGateway", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> templateCode;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "TemplateValues", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NotificationsGateway", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<ArrayOfstring> templateValues;
```

when i call the service, the soap body is sent as follows, prefixed with wrong **xmlns=""**:

```
<MobileNo xmlns="" xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NotificationsGateway">0000000000</MobileNo>
<RefrenceId xmlns="" xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NotificationsGateway">123</RefrenceId>
<TemplateCode xmlns="" xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NotificationsGateway">123</TemplateCode>
```

if i removed the **xmlns=""** and used this soap request in sopui, the service works fine, so i want to know how to remove this **xmlns=""** from the request, the code i am using is as follows:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factoryBean = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factoryBean.setServiceClass(INotificationGateway.class);
factoryBean.setAddress("https://localhost:4431/NotificationsGateway/NotificationGateway.svc");
INotificationGateway port = (INotificationGateway) factoryBean.create();

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());

HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

http.getAuthorization().setUserName("myuser");
http.getAuthorization().setPassword("mypass");
TLSClientParameters tlsCP = new TLSClientParameters();
if (ignoreSSL)
    tlsCP.setTrustManagers(createIgnoredTrustManager());
tlsCP.setDisableCNCheck(true);
http.setTlsClientParameters(tlsCP);

Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();

Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();

outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "myuser");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, ClientPasswordCallback.class.getName());

WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
port.sendSMS(sendSMSNotificationRequest);
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: You can follow the tutorial https://recalll.co/app/?q=How%20to%20remove%20namespace%20in%20XML%20through%20java?

Answer (score 1):

By default, JAX-WS (and thus CXF) produces unqualified schemas and messages.
Thus, only the root element is namespace qualified and the sub elements would 
not be.    If you add the namespace attribute to the @WebParam, that would 
change it for that parameter.

Alternatively, add a package-info.java with something like:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema( 
      namespace = "http://apache.org/hello_world_soap12_http/types",     
elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

to force the elements into qualified form.

Answer (score -1):

We can use [interceptors](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html) to remove the unwanted **xmlns=""** from the request.